# The largest closed set content in $A^c$

Tags: general-topology

Let $A=\{ (a,m)\in \mathbb R\times\mathbb Z\mid a^2-m^2<0   \}~ \bigcup ~\{ (a,m)\in \mathbb R\times\mathbb Z\mid a^2-m^2=0   ,\  a.m\not=0\} $.

and $A^c$ its complementary , I want to determine the largest closed set content in $A^c$.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does A = { (a,m) in R×Z : $a^2 <= m^2,$ a,m /= 0 } or by a. m do you mean the product am?

Comment: a.m=0 if one of them is 0